# AWS Sagemaker - Install External Library and Make it Persist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have a sagemaker instance up and running and I have a few libraries that I frequently use with it but each time I restart the instance they get wiped and I have to reinstall them. Is it possible to install my libraries to one of the anaconda environments and have the change remain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The supported way to do this for Sagemaker notebook instances is with **Lifecycle Configurations**.

You can create an **onStart** lifecycle hook that can install the required packages into the respective Conda environments each time your notebook instance starts.

Please see the following blog post for more details

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-your-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instances-with-lifecycle-configurations-and-the-option-to-disable-internet-access/

Comment: @ardix this is the correct answer to the quesion asked.

Answer (score 2):

When creating you model, you can specify the requirements.txt as an environment variable.

For Eg.

```
env = {
    'SAGEMAKER_REQUIREMENTS': 'requirements.txt', # path relative to `source_dir` below.
}
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://mybucket/modelTarFile,
                                  role = role,
                                  entry_point = 'entry.py',
                                  code_location = 's3://mybucket/runtime-code/',
                                  source_dir = 'src',
                                  env = env,
                                  name = 'model_name',
                                  sagemaker_session = sagemaker_session,
                                 )
```

This would ensure that the requirements file is run after the docker container is created, before running any code on it.

Comment: If I want to have a library persist in a jupyter notebook instance is that possible with a similar method?

Comment: Yes you can. Make sure you put the 'requirements.txt' in a sub directory of the Jupyter notebook and mention that directory in the source_directory argument as mention in the above answer.